# PHP, fopen() can't create new file out of the site's root directory

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying a demo provided by *PHP and MySQL Web Development 5th Edition* .
Here is my code

```
    $outPut="test";
    $fp=fopen("$documentRoot/../orders/orders.txt", 'ab');
    fwrite($fp,$outPut);
```

The new file should be created in www/wwwroot/orders, but no new files, and no errors.

I'm on nginx1.20.1, PHP7.4, Debian 10.
The permission of orders/ folder is 775, owner is www. I have tried 777 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please try using relative path. e.g.  `$fp=fopen("./orders/orders.txt", 'ab');` (you are creating or appending binary data, right ? otherwise remove the b from the mode parameter)

Comment: @KenLee thank you, but both methods make no difference.

Comment: Just to double-check: (1) do  you have a folder "orders" directly under the web folder which holds your PHP file ? (2)  Is the permission of this folder set as "777" as you have stated in your post ? (3) Please remove the "b" from your fopen statement, normally to write a text string you may use something like $fp = fopen("./orders/orders.txt", "w") . (4) Finally please also add fclose($fp); to the end of the script . Thanks

Comment: @KenLee the script PHP file is in /www/wwwroot/myweb.com/, and I want to save orders.txt in /www/wwwroot/orders (this may be a little bit confusing, but I just want to follow the demo script provided by the book). I have followed all your instructions but that still doesn't work. I forgot to mention that I can always create a new file in /www/wwwroot/myweb.com/orders/ successfully.

Comment: @KenLee And I have a new question, I don't really understand why I should add the parameter 'b', this book says that is an option always recommended, and all parameters in this book are things like 'ab' 'rb'...

Comment: First, try changing to use $fp=fopen("../orders/orders.txt", 'ab'); and see the effect. On the other hand, You are trying to create/save your file across directories. Please check whether **safe mode** (or other security measures) is enabled in your system. (if it is enabled, it may disallow you from doing so). The "b" parameter can be ignored first.

Comment: @KenLee Thank you so much, it works after I enabled open_basedir. But why PHP doesn't give any error messages?

Comment: You need to enable error display such as `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); `otherwise PHP will not display all types of errors. Anyway great to know that you have fixed the problem.